# Why does Gson serializes runtime type in list, not specified compile-time type?

Tags: java, json, generics, types, gson

Why does it seem that Gson ignores the nested generic type declaration when serializing?

I am trying to get Gson to use the compile-time type I specify, instead of the runtime type of objects in the list. I am also using an abstract superclass for `A.java`, but the example below has the same problem.

```
public class A {
    public String foo;
}

public class B extends A {
    public String bar;
}

public static void main( String[] args ) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    B b = new B();
    b.foo = "foo";
    b.bar = "bar";

    List<A> list = new ArrayList<A>();
    list.add(b);

    System.out.println(gson.toJson(b, new TypeToken<A>(){}.getType()));
    System.out.println(gson.toJson(b, new TypeToken<B>(){}.getType()));

    System.out.println(gson.toJson(list, new TypeToken<List<A>>(){}.getType()));
    System.out.println(gson.toJson(list, new TypeToken<List<B>>(){}.getType()));
}
```

Output:

```
{"foo":"foo"}
{"bar":"bar","foo":"foo"}
[{"bar":"bar","foo":"foo"}]
[{"bar":"bar","foo":"foo"}]
```

Expected:

```
{"foo":"foo"}
{"bar":"bar","foo":"foo"}
[{"foo":"foo"}]
[{"bar":"bar","foo":"foo"}]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I just want you to know that this is an excellent question for your first post here. I hope you participate more in the future!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### This is because of how Gson serializes collections by default.

#### Why does this happen?

**Scroll to the bottom if you don't care about why and just want a fix.**

Gson's default [`CollectionTypeAdapterFactory`](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/internal/bind/CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java) wraps it's element type adapters in something called a [`TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper`](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/internal/bind/TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java). When choosing the proper adapter, it uses [the following priorities](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/internal/bind/TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java#L46):

```
// Order of preference for choosing type adapters
// First preference: a type adapter registered for the runtime type
// Second preference: a type adapter registered for the declared type
// Third preference: reflective type adapter for the runtime type (if it is a sub class of the declared type)
// Fourth preference: reflective type adapter for the declared type
```

In this case, the Third preference is an adapter for `B`, and the Fourth preference is an adapter for A. This is not avoidable when using the default serializers, as there's [no conditional in the `CollectionTypeAdapterFactory`](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/internal/bind/CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java#L64):

```
public Adapter(Gson context, Type elementType,
    TypeAdapter<E> elementTypeAdapter,
    ObjectConstructor<? extends Collection<E>> constructor) {
  this.elementTypeAdapter =
      new TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper<E>(context, elementTypeAdapter, elementType);
  this.constructor = constructor;
}
```

This wrapper is not present when not using the `CollectionTypeAdapterFactory`, which is why it doesn't happen in your first two examples.

#### tl;dr Okay so how do I fix it?

The only way to get around this problem is to **register a custom serializer.** Writing one for `A` will do the trick, in your use case:

```
public class ATypeAdapter extends TypeAdapter<A> {
  public A read(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {
    if (reader.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
      reader.nextNull();
      return null;
    }
    reader.beginObject();
    String name = reader.nextName();
    if(!"foo".equals(name)) throw new JsonSyntaxException("Expected field named foo");
    A a = new A();
    a.foo = reader.nextString();
    reader.endObject();
    return a;
  }

  public void write(JsonWriter writer, A value) throws IOException {
    if (value == null) {
      writer.nullValue();
      return;
    }
    writer.beginObject();
    writer.name("foo");
    writer.value(value.foo);
    writer.endObject();
  }
}
```

Then, if you do:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {
    GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
    builder.registerTypeAdapter(new TypeToken<A>(){}.getType(), new ATypeAdapter());
    Gson gson = builder.create();

    B b = new B();
    b.foo = "foo";
    b.bar = "bar";

    List<A> list = new ArrayList<A>();
    list.add(b);

    System.out.println(gson.toJson(b, new TypeToken<A>(){}.getType()));
    System.out.println(gson.toJson(b, new TypeToken<B>(){}.getType()));

    System.out.println(gson.toJson(list, new TypeToken<List<A>>(){}.getType()));
    System.out.println(gson.toJson(list, new TypeToken<List<B>>(){}.getType()));
}
```

You get the expected output:

```
{"foo":"foo"}
{"bar":"bar","foo":"foo"}
[{"foo":"foo"}]
[{"bar":"bar","foo":"foo"}]
```